# How to put one div on top of another?

Tags: css, html

Basically, I want to print one div above another.

```
def(result):

   for result in results
       print_detail (result)
   print_summary ()


def print_summary():

    <div id = "attop">
    This is result summary 
    </div>



def print_detail(result_msg)

    some processing...

   """
    <div id = "atbottom">
    error details <BR>
    <div id = "toggler"> 
    <table></table> 
    </div>
    </div>
    """
```

I want to put print_summary above print_html. I tried following css but it didn't work. print_summary kinda overlaps print_detail content. Please advice.

CSS

```
#attop{
                                                position: relative;
                                                width:auto;
                                                height:30px;
                                                float:left;
                                                margin-top:97px;

 #atbottom{
                                                position: fixed;
                                                width:auto;
                                                height:auto;
                                                float:left;
```

Comment: we need to see the rendered HTML and valid CSS, with an explanation of the desired result, and what you have tried. best to setup something on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I can already tell you the bottom one can't float and needs to have a position defined

Comment: You should not need `display:block` since `<div>`'s are already block level elements. `<div>Summary</div><div>HTML</div>` should work without issue.

Comment: Matthew Rapati, The result consist of html table with toggle effect. Now the toggle is not working here after I applied css and the summary is still seen in bottom but the position seems to be little bit top than before. Should I need to raise height.